# How to get StartDate and EndDate by comparing multiple rows and columns

Tags: sql-server

I have the following data in my table:

```
ID     StartDate    EndDate 
-------------------------------
222    2019-04-01   2019-04-16
222    2019-04-16   2019-04-30
562    2019-04-01   2019-04-08
562    2019-04-08   2019-04-15
562    2019-04-15   2019-04-22
562    2019-04-22   2019-04-29
228    2019-04-02   2019-04-09
228    2019-04-10   2019-04-16
228    2019-04-15   2019-04-23
228    2019-04-26   2019-04-30
228    2019-04-01   2019-04-16
```

The condition is if `Enddate = StartDate`, then it has to check their `StartDate` and `EndDate` and the expected output as below:

```
ID      StartDate       EndDate 
-----------------------------------
222     2019-04-01      2019-04-30
562     2019-04-01      2019-04-29
```

Comment: What if the data looks like this?ID      StartDate       EndDate 
222    2019-04-01   2019-04-15
222    2019-04-16   2019-04-30

Comment: Aren't you just returning the `MIN` and `MAX` for the `StartDate` and `EndDate`  columns respectively..? What have you tired to solve this problem?

Comment: While checking the complete duration of any ID, I just have to ensure that I haven't missed any week or day.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question but this query should return the expected output: `SELECT ID, MIN(StartDate) AS StartDate, MAX(EndDate) AS EndDate FROM dbo.YourTable GROUP BY ID;`

Comment: If there is a gap of any day then Min and Max not help.

Comment: But there isn't any gaps in your data @user9952388 so `MIN` and `MAX` will do as you require. If your data does have gaps, you need to include sample data and expected results where you have gaps.  We can't answer a question for a scenario you haven't given us.

Comment: If there is gap, a single id like 562 will appear twice in your output result set... right?

Comment: I'm looking at the consecutive records, where many ID's have 7 days or 15 days duration. If ID 562 has 14 days data and their start date and EndDate in the first row is 2019-04-01 and 2019-04-08 respectively and in a second row 2019-04-08   and 2019-04-15 then expected output must be 562     2019-04-01      2019-04-215

Comment: Better you set your sample and expected result keeping a GAP between two row of a single ID.

Comment: Put your sample in your question @user9952388 . that data looks like 1 row, which doesn't match your current design. You can do so by clicking [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56406277/edit) underneath your question.

Comment: Updated the Sample Data, 
now there are three ID's out of which only 2 ID's StartDate and EndDate's re matching. Expected output is the same.

Comment: Great, thanks! I assume you're using SQL Server 2012+?

Comment: Yes, @Larnu, I know the logic, but don't know how to implement in SQL.

Comment: What is the expected output for 228?

Comment: ID 228 not satisfying the Enddate = StartDate condition hence it skipped

Comment: _h, that makes things easier, then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I would do it, using `LEAD`. You can use `LEAD` to check if the next `StartDate` has the same value as the current `EndDate`. If it does I return 0, and if not 1, and provided the `SUM` of those values is 0, we know all the dates were continuous:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ID,
           StartDate,
           EndDate,
           CASE LEAD(StartDate,1, EndDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY StartDate) WHEN EndDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsContinous
    FROM (VALUES(222,CONVERT(date,'2019-04-01'),CONVERT(date,'2019-04-16')),
                (222,CONVERT(date,'2019-04-16'),CONVERT(date,'2019-04-30')),
                (562,CONVERT(date,'2019-04-01'),CONVERT(date,'2019-04-08')),
                (562,CONVERT(date,'2019-04-08'),CONVERT(date,'2019-04-15')),
                (562,CONVERT(date,'2019-04-15'),CONVERT(date,'2019-04-22')),
                (562,CONVERT(date,'2019-04-22'),CONVERT(date,'2019-04-29')),
                (228,CONVERT(date,'2019-04-02'),CONVERT(date,'2019-04-09')),
                (228,CONVERT(date,'2019-04-10'),CONVERT(date,'2019-04-16')),
                (228,CONVERT(date,'2019-04-15'),CONVERT(date,'2019-04-23')),
                (228,CONVERT(date,'2019-04-26'),CONVERT(date,'2019-04-30')),
                (228,CONVERT(date,'2019-04-01'),CONVERT(date,'2019-04-16'))) V (ID, StartDate, EndDate))
SELECT ID,
       MIN(StartDate) AS StartDate,
       MAX(EndDate) AS EndDate
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ID
HAVING SUM(IsContinous) = 0;
```

Comment: Hello @Lamu, How could we handle below ?<br/><br/>ExternalID Extract_StartDate Extract_EndDate IsContinous<br/>
2180 2019-05-05 2019-05-12 1<br/>
2180 2019-05-10 2019-05-17 1<br/>
218130 2019-05-12 2019-05-19 1<br/>
218130 2019-05-12 2019-05-19 1<br/>
2180 2019-05-17 2019-05-24 1<br/>
2180 2019-05-17 2019-05-24 1<br/>
2180 2019-05-19 2019-05-26 1<br/>
2180 2019-05-24 2019-05-31 0<br/>

Comment: Hello @Lamu, How could we handle below ?

ExternalID Extract_StartDate Extract_EndDate IsContinous
2180 2019-05-05 2019-05-12 1
2180 2019-05-10 2019-05-17 1
218130 2019-05-12 2019-05-19 1
218130 2019-05-12 2019-05-19 1
2180 2019-05-17 2019-05-24 1
2180 2019-05-17 2019-05-24 1
2180 2019-05-19 2019-05-26 1
2180 2019-05-24 2019-05-31 0

Comment: Ask a new question if you have a new problem @user9952388 . That data is unreadable in comments.